# Jquery Validation, how do I run custom code if there are errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I want to check for validation on multiple fields in a form. If there are any errors whatsoever I want to run some custom jQuery to hide and show various elements.

I have the validation below, my question is how do I now check if there are errors to run my custom code?

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            username: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            topic: {
                required: "#newsletter:checked",
                minlength: 2
            },
            agree: "required"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `form()` method after the `validate`:

```
if($('form')
      .validate(RULES)
      .form()){
    //put your code here
}
```

See the documentation for the [Validator Object](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation#Validator).